# Where to close the class? Java

Tags: java

I have coded this little program here, but I don't know where to close the curly bracket of the class MiniMusicPlayer3, any ideas?
I have copied this code, that's why I am not sure where to close it, but if I close it at the really end instead of 1 error I get 13 errors.. xD

```
    public class MiniMusicPlayer3 {
```

Above is the part of code I need to close.

```
import j.avax.sound.midi.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class MiniMusicPlayer3 {

static JFrame f = new JFrame("My First Music Video");
static MyDrawPanel ml;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MiniMusicPlayer3 mini = new MiniMusicPlayer3();
    mini.go();

} //close methoda


public void setUpGui() {
    ml = new MyDrawPanel();
    f.setContentPane(ml);
    f.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
} //close methode


public void go() {
    setUpGui();

    try {
        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencer.open();
        sequencer.addControllerEventListener(ml, new int[] {
            127
        });
        Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
        Track track = seq.createTrack();

        int r = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += 4) {

            r = (int)(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
            track.add(makeEvent(144, 1, r, 100, i));
            track.add(makeEvent(176, 1, 127, 0, i));
            track.add(makeEvent(128, 1, r, 100, i + 2));

        } //end loop


        sequencer.setSequence(seq);
        sequencer.start();
        sequencer.setTempoInBPM(120);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: at the end of the class.
I hate to sound negative, but if this is something you can't figure out on your own, you clearly don't know Java well enough to be working with this code. Start learning from the beginning, copying code and looking at it won't teach you nearly as much as actual practice will.

Comment: I guess I explained myself in the wrong way @Stultuske , you see this is a code which I'm studying in a book of Java (Head First Java to be exact) and I have found out, testing it, that we're missing a curly bracket, that's why I've decided to come here and try to have some help ;)

Comment: the answer doesn't change, though. a class is modeled like this:  public class ClassName{ /* implementation */ }
so, in your case, you'll need to add the closing bracket after the last bracket you have there.
You can't possibly have methods that are not inside a class, you don't declare a second (inner) class there, so those methods must be members of that class, and the last } there is the closing of the method

Comment: as for your new errors, this might cause a few: import j.avax.sound.midi.*;

Comment: I guess it's better if I let that go.. thanks by the way

Comment: what I meant was: there is no j.avax package, remove the . in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequence;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequencer;


public class MiniMusicPlayer3 {

static JFrame f = new JFrame("My First Music Video");
static MyDrawPanel ml;
public static void main(String[] args) {
 MiniMusicPlayer3 mini = new MiniMusicPlayer3();
 mini.go();

} //close methoda


public void setUpGui() {
 ml = new MyDrawPanel();
 f.setContentPane(ml);
 f.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
 f.setVisible(true);
} //close methode


public void go() {
 setUpGui();

 try {
    Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
    sequencer.open();
    sequencer.addControllerEventListener(ml, new int[] {
        127
    });
    Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
    javax.sound.midi.Track track = seq.createTrack();

    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += 4) {

        r = (int)(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
        track.add(makeEvent(144, 1, r, 100, i));
        track.add(makeEvent(176, 1, 127, 0, i));
        track.add(makeEvent(128, 1, r, 100, i + 2));

    } //end loop


    sequencer.setSequence(seq);
    sequencer.start();
    sequencer.setTempoInBPM(120);
 } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
}//this was the last curly you need to put at the end of your code
```

Comment: Yes I already fixed that, you're right, but I just found out I need more code in order to make this one work, hen I'll have to wait the end of the book for the rest part, thanks a lot by the way for your help, it helps!

Comment: what are you trying to implement? do you want to play an audio file using Java?